# Select RadioButton based on database value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Working on MVC 5 app.

I have a table with a bunch of columns. One column contains a radio button list of items. Since this is an "edit" view I need to pre-populate the selected radio button properly. (ie select the item that's in the db)

Part of my controller code...

```
 newVmRecord.SurveyAnswerOption = 
       new SelectList(db.SurveyAnswerOptions, 
           "AnswerOptionText", "AnswerOptionText", ar.SurveyAnswer);
```

Here's the razor:

```
  @foreach (SelectListItem item in 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model[i].SurveyAnswerOption)
  {
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer, 
        Model[i].SurveyAnswerOption, new { @Checked = 
        Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer}) @item.Text
  }
```

The available options are 'yes', 'no' and 'n/a'. In the database, for example, if 'no' was already selected then it should be pre-selected when this view loads. The radio buttons appear correctly, but, the @Checked doesn't work correctly.

By the way, I am sure there is existing data because I put this line of code as the first line the foreach....

```
  @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you confirmed that ar.Survey is being populated and there are no casting issues (ie. true/false, yes/no, 1/0)?

Comment: @KevinRaffay yes. There is data. I tried adding this in the first line of the foreach and it shows data: @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer);

Comment: Welll if @checked is translated the `checked` attribute on the html ... it should just accept the word `checked` or ' '... so what about

```@Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer, 
        Model[i].SurveyAnswerOption, new { @Checked = 
        Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer == "yes" ? "checked" : ""}```

Comment: I agree with David -- I recall that "checked" is the attribute.

Comment: Actually, you don't even want `checked=""` because simply having the checked attribute makes some browsers check the radio button, so using David's example above will end up with the last radio button in the set being checked, regardless of which one has `checked="checked"`. This messiness with the radio button is why I typically opt for dropdowns instead. Quick [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sleeyuen/7zo3mtm9/) to illustrate.

Comment: Your code really makes no sense. Your setting the `checked` attribute for all buttons (`checked="checked" or `checked="anything"` makes the radio button checked) and since only one can be checked, the last one will be. And `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is for use in a dropdownlist and makes no sense for radio buttons

Comment: You need to generate 3 radio buttons for your property - say `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.yourProperty, "yes")` (ditto for `"no" and "n/a") and if the value of `yourProperty` is `"yes"` then the 1st radio button will be selected (and if its `"no"`, then the 2nd will be)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
@foreach (SelectListItem item in (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model[i].SurveyAnswerOption)
  {
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer,@item.Value, Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer == item.Value ? new {Checked = "checked"} : null) @item.Text
  }
```